# Quitar hash de autenticación en laravel

Tags: laravel, hash

*¡Sé que no es lo correcto hacer un login de esta manera!*
Tengo una tabla con password no encriptado en `hash`, ¿cómo podría lograr quitar la verificación de `hash` en el campo password de laravel?

Actualmente lo tengo así:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request){
        /**
         * Autentificacion de usuario:
         * 
         */

       if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

            $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            return redirect('home');

        }else{
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

Pero ¿cómo podría hacerlo en forma de texto crudo al pasarle el password?

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en el código que veo, sería una implementación en el momento incorrecto, pues `authenticated`, como su nombre lo dice en inglés, significa que el usuario ya fue autenticado, entonces podríamos decir que es un poco tarde.

Yo lo haría en el método `attemptLogin` (aunque hay soluciones mucho mejor elaboradas que esta), pero hay que tener en cuenta lo que implica jugar con este método:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

¿Qué hay que tener en cuenta? todo lo que hace el método `attempt` en el Guard respectivo, por ejemplo los eventos que son lanzados:

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
        $this->login($user, $remember);

        return true;
    }

    // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
    // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
    // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
    $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);

    return false;
}
```

No haré la implementación como tal porque creo que es realmente sencilla, y porque desconozco lo que haya en el Guard `admin`.